# How can I make scoring system on SQL?

Tags: php, sql-server, ranking, rank, tabular

I want to add scoring - ranking system to my web-page.

The web-page is using some information from SQL, my main problem is:

There is a table in SQL, which shows inventory of players. In this table:

> `CharID | Slots (of inventory) | User Item ID`

Another tables which show "User Item ID" are:

> `Item ID Number | values of item (with count)`

For example; In this table;

> User Item ID | Item ID | Opt Level ( Plus value of an item like ; 90
>   level + 7 )

I want to create a new table, which has:

> User Item ID | Item ID with item point, | And it must be add (Opt
>   Level) to item point)

Same like:

> User Name | User Item ID | Item ID with item point | Opt level | Total
>   Point
>
> xxx ------------------- 5 --------------------90 ---------------------7 ----------97

But I don't have an idea how to do that. And after created this item points, highest score must be on the top of the rank.

Anyone got any ideas?

With pictures;

[image: http://prntscr.com/6fqumn]

This is the first table I can see Member ID , Member's Inventory Slot and What the Member is using.

[image: http://prntscr.com/6fqvag]

This is the second table  I can see ID64 is same With member using, RefItemID id is different, OptLevel is Item Point, MagParamNum is item point too.

So, I want to creat a new table CharID (1st pic)  -- User Item ID (1st-2nd pic) --- OptLvel (2nd pic) --- MagParamNum (2nd Pic)  -- Total Point ( OpLevel + MagParamNum + The Score I gave the item )

Comment: your English is not that bad, but I still can't understand the question.
What exactly do you want to store in the new table and how does your current data looks like?

Comment: Edited first post with pictures, its really hard to tell..

Comment: You need to have a table to collect the scores, then have a table that collects the userid. and you need to have the userid as a foreign key in the score table

Comment: Yes! Thats a problem, i dont know anything how can i do that.. Anyone can help me for create table and how can i collect them :)
1st table name - dbo._Inventory -- 2nd table name - dbo._Items

Comment: @Dtractus, I can give you a general idea of how to go about it.  Because I don't entirely understand your question. I just have an idea of what you wish to achieve

Comment: @Dtractus You know how to create a table in sql-server ? and are you using PDO or sqlsrv ?

Comment: @kya yes i know how to create table and im using mssql :) Oldies but goldies :D i really wonder about your idea :)

Comment: @Dtractus you dont need to create a new table as that data already exists. You need to create a view

Comment: @kya But how can i do that ranking system like that? Example; localhost?topic=itemranking .. Like this : http://prntscr.com/6fr3ba :/

Comment: i can call username etc etc but itempoints is important for me..

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to create a new table containing all that information as it already exist in other tables.

You need to have the userid as a foreign key in the item table, to help you identify which item belongs to which user.

I am not sure where storing the optLevel, but I am assuming you are storing it in a different table called optTable.

What you need to do is to create a View in your SQL database:

```
CREATE VIEW [newTable] AS
SELECT u.userid, u.username, i.itemPoint, o.optLevel, (i.itemPoint+o.optLevel) AS Total
FROM userTable u
INNER JOIN itemTable i ON u.userid = i.userid
INNER JOIN optTable o ON u.userid = o.userid`
ORDER by (i.itemPoint + o.optLevel) DESC
```

Once you have created this view, information and calculations will be done and stored for you on the database.

Before creating a view or adding a new user, you need to check if that that user doesn't exist, but you will do that in your php code or have a method that will

```
> SELECT COUNT(username) FROM username.
```

You can then access the view by typing:

```
SELECT * 
FROM newTable
WHERE userid = $id
```